# Auto Swap External CSS Stylesheet with toggle scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to get this script to toggle back to original CSS external stylesheet.

I have the following code that works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#css-master2").click(function() {
$("link[title=change]").attr({href : "css/master2.css"});
});
});
```

Whenever someone clicks on anything with id #css-master2  it changes the external style sheet to master2.css (that part works fine).

What I would like it do is change back to the original master1.css if they click on it again. Something like toggle?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the link tag's href, if it equals master2, switch back to master1 like the same way above.

Can't think about why you'd do this, considering the exact thing can be done using css classes instead of two different files.

Comment: I am adding a logo at the top of the site for the blind. Swapping the whole external theme to color safe. I only have one button. How do i have the href tag to have two id tags? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: what do you mean by "external theme". You can probably achieve the same thing by applying different class to a root node (html/body) right?

Comment: Perhaps I could do it that way. I have two external css files (different themes). I guess I could just make a seperate button and call the id. I was hoping for a swap on a single id button.

Comment: You could swap it with a single button too. You need to check what's the current value of link tag's href. Based on that you can swap to the other value.